# Python 3 - print order of for loop result

Tags: python

I have written a script in Python 3.6 which queries API data to return a postal address from a zip code.

The script is as follows:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse 

main_api = 'http://link.to.api_site/json?'
key = 'AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz0123456789'
address = '90210'

url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address':address, 'key':key})

json_data = requests.get(url).json()

for result in json_data["results"][0]["address_components"]:
    print(result["long_name"])
```

The issue is have is the order the JSON data is given. When I run a query from the web browser the data is shown:

```
{
   "results" : [
     {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "90210",
           "short_name" : "90210",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Beverly Hills",
           "short_name" : "Beverly Hills",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Los Angeles County",
           "short_name" : "Los Angeles County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "California",
           "short_name" : "CA",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
```

so when the For loop runs it returns the data in the following order:

```
90210
Beverly Hills
Los Angeles County
California
United States
```

What I would prefer is for the address to be printed out in a different order:

```
Beverly Hills
Los Angeles County
California
United States
90210
```

So question is, is there a way to change the order when the results of the For loop are printed out.

Comment: The *"wrong order"* is the correct order as far as the data you're getting is concerned. If you want a different order, you will have to be explicit about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to do it is to store each information into variables and then you print each content in the correct order that you want:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse 

main_api = 'http://link.to.api_site/json?'
key = 'AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz0123456789'
address = '90210'

url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address':address, 'key':key})

json_data = requests.get(url).json()

area_code = json_data["results"][0]["address_components"][0]["long_name"]
area = json_data["results"][0]["address_components"][1]["long_name"]
county = json_data["results"][0]["address_components"][2]["long_name"]
state = json_data["results"][0]["address_components"][3]["long_name"]
country = json_data["results"][0]["address_components"][4]["long_name"]

print(area)
print(county)
print(state)
print(country)
print(area_code)
```

You could also print the content of the list except for the first  one and then "manually" the first one.

Maybe something like this? (I'm not sure this works, I haven't tested it).

```
for result in json_data["results"][0]["address_components"][1:]:
    print(result["long_name"])
print(json_data["results"][0]["address_components"][1]["long_name"])
```

Comment: this worked:print(json_data["results"][0]["address_components"][0]["long_name"]) - the first solution is what i had originally but it fails when you type in a code from a different country. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this;

```
order_to_print = ["locality", "administrative_area_level_2", "administrative_area_level_1", "country", "postal_code"]

for order in order_to_print:
    for result in json_data["results"][0]["address_components"]:
        if result["types"][0] == order:
            print(result["long_name"])
```

But I think it wouldn't be possible without defining the order like above.